# Postgresql : Global replace all foreign key references to a row with another

Tags: django, postgresql

I am using postgres with Django.

I have a table of users. The rows are referenced in other tables as foreign keys.

Some times, we want to merge two user rows into one. We want to replace all references to a particular row with another. Is this possible?

Comment: [This](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/122306/242866) sounds pretty much exactly like your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It is above my SQL skills. Still going through to adapt one of the solutions to my requirements. I am also surprised there is no 'standard' simple solution as I would expect this as a common problem.